# Grunt doesn't run json_server task from grunt-json-server

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs, server

I am using the configuration the npm page gives an example for, yet when I try to run the task using either `grunt.run.task (['json_server'])` or in `concurrent: { server: { tasks [ 'json_server'] } }`, grunt doesn't even print out the task name in the console. It doesn't even give me an error if I remove the db file it tries to point to.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://github.com/tfiwm/grunt-json-server/issues/4

The library uses registerMultiTask; when changed to registerTask, it worked fine for me.